# How to solve problem with drawing Chart in Scene Builder with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have problem with my program.
I want to draw chart after providing data (coefficients of the equation).

I tried to change my import (it helped with some variables)
I changed java.awt* for javafx.scene ... (few imports).

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="grahps.Controller">
<children>
        <TextField fx:id="factorA" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="598.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" text="a=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="75.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="factorB" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="630.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" text="b=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="37.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="factorC" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="674.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" text="c=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="158.0" layoutY="592.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="xMin=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="61.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="158.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="522.0" fx:id="xMin" />
        <TextField layoutX="158.0" layoutY="650.0" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="xMax=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="3.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="158.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="522.0" fx:id="xMax" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="468.0" layoutY="629.0" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="276.0" text="f(x)=" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="468.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="56.0">
            <font>
                <Font size="18.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <LineChart fx:id="drawChart" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="800.0" title="Chart">
            <xAxis>
                <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
            </xAxis>
            <yAxis>
                <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
            </yAxis>
        </LineChart>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="612.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="Rysuj wykres" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The part with LineChart (fx:id="drawChart") generated communicate: "Unresolved fx:id reference

My main class:

```
package grahps;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    private Controller controller;//

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.show();


        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml").getPath());
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        controller.drawChart(stage);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And finally my controller:

```
package grahps;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    TextField factorA;
    @FXML
    TextField factorB;
    @FXML
    TextField factorC;
    @FXML
    TextField xMin;
    @FXML
    TextField xMax;
    @FXML
    Label label;
    @FXML
    Button button;
    @FXML
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> chart;

    //Parser Text Field -> double
    double xMax1 = Double.parseDouble(xMax.getText());
    double xMin1 = Double.parseDouble(xMin.getText());
    double a = Double.parseDouble(factorA.getText());
    double b = Double.parseDouble(factorB.getText());
    double c = Double.parseDouble(factorC.getText());

    @FXML
    public void drawChart(Stage stage) {
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = chart;
        series.setName("Chart");

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(xMin1, xMax1, 1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setTickUnit(1);
        xAxis.setLabel("X Label");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y Label");
        final javafx.scene.chart.LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new javafx.scene.chart.LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        double y;

        String pattern;
        if (a == 0 && c == 0) {
            pattern = "f(x)=" + factorB;
            label.setText(pattern);
        } else if (c == 0) {
            pattern = "f(x)=" + factorA + "x+" + factorB;
            label.setText(pattern);
            for (double i = xMin1; i <= xMax1; i++) {
                y = a * i + b;
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, y));
            }
        } else {
            pattern = "f(x)=" + factorC + "x^2" + factorA + "x+" + factorB;
            label.setText(pattern);
            for (double i = xMin1; i < xMax1; i++) {
                y = a * i * i + b * i + c;
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, y));
            }
        }

        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Please notice one thing: this is my first JavaFX project.
Simply I want to fill in coefficients of the equation and generate equation pattern + draw chart after clicking button.

I'll be greaftul for help.

When I deleted @FXML annotation above method and compiled code I got those errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Damian/IdeaProjects/Graphs/target/classes/fxml/sample.fxml:14

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at grahps.Main.start(Main.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grahps.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application grahps.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also I changed onAction="drawChart" for onAction="chart" and now I can see highlighted communicate: "cannot set javafx.scene.control.LineChart to chart"

Comment: don't see a field drawChart ...

Comment: I think @FXML annotation above public void drawChart(Stage stage) method is extra, try removing it.

Comment: repeating: you do not have a __field__ with id _drawChart_ (the field name is _chart_)

Comment: @FXML
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> chart;
It should be different type?

Comment: Change `LineChart (fx:id="drawChart")` to `LineChart (fx:id="chart")`

Comment: It didn't help. I still didn't solve problem.

Comment: Apart from the missing reference, the code contains other bugs, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs in the code, e.g.:

- The `//Parser Text Field -> double`-block in the controller is executed too early => `NullPointerException`.
- When calling `controller.drawChart(stage)` in the `start`-method `controller` equals `null` => `NullPointerException`.
- In the `drawChart`-method in the controller `series` equals `null`, because `chart` equals `null` => `NullPointerException`.
- A reference to the chart is missing in the controller. This has already been noted in the comments.
- `CategoryAxis` is used as the type of the x-axis, although the x-data are numerical values.

Before fixing these bugs, the architecture should be improved (this will automatically fix some of the bugs):

- `Controller`-class: Since the chart has to be initialized and then updated with every click on the button, the following changes in the controller would be useful:

  1. Implement an `initialize`-method, in which the necessary initializations can be made.
  2. Implement an `updateChart`-method, which is called when the button is clicked and which updates the chart.
  3. Define a reference to the LineChart.
  4. Define references to both axes.

  Thus, the `Controller`-class looks as follows:

  ```
  public class Controller {
      @FXML
      TextField factorA;
      @FXML
      TextField factorB;
      @FXML
      TextField factorC;
      @FXML
      TextField xMin;
      @FXML
      TextField xMax;
      @FXML
      Label label;
      @FXML
      Button button;
      @FXML
      LineChart<Number, Number> chart; 
      @FXML
      NumberAxis xAxis;
      @FXML
      NumberAxis yAxis;
      @FXML
      public void updateChart() {/*ToDo*/}
      public void initialize(){/*ToDo*/}
  }
  ```
- `Main`-class: In the `start`-method only the FXML needs to be loaded:

  ```
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
  }
  ```
- FXML: The following changes should be made:

  1. Change the ID of the LineChart to `fx:id="chart"`
  2. Change the type of the x-axis of the LineChart to `NumberAxis`
  3. Add `onAction="#updateChart"` to the button. This calls the `updateChart`-method when the button is clicked.
  4. Define an ID for both axes (`fx:id="xAxis"` and `fx:id="yAxis"`).
  5. Remove all initializations with non-numeric characters (e.g. `text="a="`) for all text fields, otherwise there are problems with parsing (it makes more sense to use labels or watermarks, e.g. `promptText="a"`).

  Then, the FXML becomes:

  ```
  <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="grahps.Controller">
      <children>
          <TextField fx:id="factorA" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="75.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" promptText="a" />
          <TextField fx:id="factorB" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="37.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" promptText="b" />
          <TextField fx:id="factorC" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="106.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="24.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="670.0" promptText="c" />
          <TextField fx:id="xMin" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="120.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="61.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="158.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="522.0" promptText="xMin" />
          <TextField fx:id="xMax" prefHeight="47.0" prefWidth="120.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="3.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="158.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="522.0" promptText="xMax" />
          <Label fx:id="label" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="276.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="30.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="468.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="56.0" text="f(x)=" >
              <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
              </font>
          </Label>
          <LineChart fx:id="chart" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="800.0" title="Chart">
              <xAxis>
                  <NumberAxis fx:id="xAxis" side="BOTTOM" />
              </xAxis>
              <yAxis>
                  <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
              </yAxis>
          </LineChart>
          <Button fx:id="button" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="98.0" layoutX="317.0" layoutY="612.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Rysuj wykres" onAction="#updateChart" />
      </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  ```

With these changes, an empty chart is displayed when the application is started (since no initialization has yet been implemented). Clicking on the button has no effect (since no updating has yet been implemented).

- Initialization:

  ```
  public void initialize(){       
      initChartProperties();
      initInputControls();        
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = getSeries();        
      chart.getData().add(series);
  }
  ```

  The `getSeries`-method essentially contains the logic of the `drawChart`-method:

  ```
  private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> getSeries() {

      double xMax1 = Double.parseDouble(xMax.getText());
      double xMin1 = Double.parseDouble(xMin.getText());
      double a = Double.parseDouble(factorA.getText());
      double b = Double.parseDouble(factorB.getText());
      double c = Double.parseDouble(factorC.getText());

      XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
      series.setName("Chart");

      String pattern;
      if (a == 0 && c == 0) {
          pattern = "f(x)=" + factorB.getText();
          label.setText(pattern);
      } else if (c == 0) {
          pattern = "f(x)=" + factorA.getText() + "x+" + factorB.getText();
          label.setText(pattern);
          for (double i = xMin1; i <= xMax1; i++) {
              double y = a * i + b;
              series.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(i, y));
          }
      } else {
          pattern = "f(x)=" + factorA.getText() + "x^2+" + factorB.getText() + "x+" + factorC.getText();
          label.setText(pattern);
          for (double i = xMin1; i < xMax1; i++) {
              double y = a * i * i + b * i + c;
              series.getData().add(new Data<Number, Number>(i, y));
          }
      }

      return series;
  }
  ```

  The `initInputControls`-method initializes the input controls, e.g.:

  ```
  private void initInputControls() {
      xMax.setText("100.0");
      xMin.setText("10.0");
      factorA.setText("1.0");
      factorB.setText("2.0");
      factorC.setText("3.0");
  }
  ```

  The `initChartProperties`-method initializes the chart:

  ```
  private void initChartProperties() {
      chart.setAnimated(true);
      xAxis.setLabel("X Label");
      yAxis.setLabel("Y Label");      
  }
  ```

  If you want to display an empty chart at startup, simply remove the last three lines in the `initialize`-method.
- Updating: Updating simply deletes the old series and adds the new series to the chart:

  ```
  @FXML
  public void updateChart() {     
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = getSeries();
      chart.getData().clear();
      chart.getData().add(series);
  }
  ```

After these changes, the application behaves as expected. The figure on the left shows the application after startup, the figure on the right after updating the input values.

[image]

Some things can still be improved, e.g. the application does not scale properly if the window size is changed. In addition, the validation of the input fields is missing. Chart animation can be disabled in the `initChartProperties`-method.

**UPDATE:**
If no symbols are to be displayed, add in the `initChartProperties`-method:

```
chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you mate for help, it's actually almost all I wanted.
I changed init. values (all  for = 0).
I would change few things also: the type of chart - I want have line graph, not like this (set of points)? How to change it?

Comment: Just add `chart.setCreateSymbols(false);` to the `initChartProperties`-method.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I just changed all default values in init method for 0.

Ok, how to set this chart as line chart, not set of points?

Comment: It should work, see new figure in the Update-section of my answer. And what exactly does "It doesn't work" mean? Are the markers still there?

Comment: Ok, now everything is fine, I don't know why it didn't work for the first time.
Last question - how to set default label text as "f(x)= " ?
label.setText("f(x)= "); in initChartProperties() method doesn't change anything.

Comment: The solution depends on what exactly is defined as the _default_ case. If the default case is defined as `a = b = c = 0`, one possibility is to add the following case: `if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {pattern = "f(x)=";label.setText(pattern);} else if (a == 0 && c == 0){...` in the `getSeries`-method. If the default case is merely the _initial_ call, one possibility is to set `label.setText("f(x)=");` at the end of the `initialize`-method (here it is important to set the label _after_ the `getSeries`-call, otherwise it is overwritten).

Comment: Ok, I got it. Last question (I hope) - how to do validation of input data? I want only int (or double) values.

Comment: Possible validations are: All fields are mandatory, all fields are numeric, `xMax > xMin` and value range validations such as `aMin < a < aMax`. You can use third-party libraries that supports validations, such as [controlsfx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) or (since you have only a few validations) implement your own validation. There are questions/answers in SO on this topic. Overall, however, the validations-theme is too complex and extensive to be discussed in commentaries. Try to implement one of the proposed solutions, and if you get stuck post a _new_ question on SO.